# Improve my code to reduce time during a loop

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I have 2 dataframes: dataframeA with 200 000 lines and dataframeB with 83 000 lines.

I want to compare 2 columns in each files and i want to know the match %. The 2 columns are city and name.
If my name in dataframeA is the same (or almost) in the dataframeB with the same city in both side, I want to obtain a new dataframeC to see the entire line with columns from both dataframe A and B.

My code is running and working for a sample (250 lines in dataframeB and 200 000 lines in dataframeA)
But when I want to use my entire dataframeB (2 000 lines = 1h), it is still running...

see my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy
import string # pour charger une librairie de ponctuation (string.punctuation)
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

city_city = set(dataframeA['CODE city']).intersection(set(dataframeB['CODE city']))

result_rows = []

def calculate_match_percentage(str1, str2):
return fuzz.ratio(str1.lower(), str2.lower())

for city in city_city:
result_selection = dataframeA[dataframeA['CODE city'] == city]
categorie_selection = dataframeB[dataframeB['Code city'] == city]

for index_A, row_A in result_selection.iterrows():
    for index_B, row_B in categorie_selection.iterrows():
        A_string = str(row_A['name'])
        B_string = str(row_B['name'])
        match_percentage = calculate_match_percentage(A_string.lower(), B_string.lower())
        if match_percentage > 80:
            result_dict = {col: row_A[col] for col in dataframeA.columns}
            result_dict.update({col: row_sirene[col] for col in dataframeB.columns})
            result_dict["match"] = match_percentage  # Ajouter le pourcentage de match
            result_rows.append(result_dict)
```

How can I improve my code to reduce the time ?

Comment: What is the asymptotic complexity of the algorithm used? Where, after profiling, do you find most time spent here? Also, the code above isn't formatted correctly, so it's not useful for a question here. Please provide a [mcve]! BTW: An obvious thing seems to be to move the line `A_string = ..` out of the inner loop. There are further, similar operations that are performed redundantly.

Comment: `str(row_A['name'])`, `{col: row_A[col] for col in dataframeA.columns}` and `{col: row_sirene[col] for col in dataframeB.columns}` are *recomputed* over and over for no reasons. They can be precomputed. In fact, the union of both too. You can pre-create the field `"match"` and copy the precomputed dict. However, it does not make any sense to duplicate the same information `16_600_000_000 * match_ratio` times where `match_ratio` is the probability of the `if` to be taken... If `match_ratio` is 1%, then the result will take >10 GiB of RAM. All of this is not reasonable IMHO.